# Xamarin traffic network data usage by application

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm creating a Xamarin app Visual Studio 2022 to monitor network traffic of specific Spotify and Google Maps apps using Android.Net.TrafficStats and outputting data to a CSV file with download and upload in megabytes (MB) as well as download and upload speeds in MB per second.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXFem.png)

I have a problem using the library Android.Net.TrafficStats which identifies that the method does not exist "using Android.Net.TrafficStats;"

I'm also not able to get the uid of the application, for example spotify, using the method: int spotifyUid = TrafficStats.GetUidRxBytes(TrafficType.Mobile, PackageManager.GetPackageUid("com.spotify.android"));

The errors are:
CS0138 A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'TrafficStats' is a type, not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' NetUsage directive

CS0103 The name "TrafficType" does not exist in the current NetUsage context

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

```
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Net;
using Android.Net.TrafficStats;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

// Get the UID of the Spotify app based on its package name
int spotifyUid = TrafficStats.GetUidRxBytes(TrafficType.Mobile, PackageManager.GetPackageUid("com.spotify.android"));
long previousRxBytes = TrafficStats.GetUidRxBytes(spotifyUid);

// Specify the path for the CSV file
string csvFilePath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "SpotifyTraffic.csv");

// Create a CSV file and write headers
File.WriteAllText(csvFilePath, "Timestamp,Download (MB),Upload (MB),Download Speed (MB/s),Upload Speed (MB/s)\n");

// Monitor and record network traffic periodically
while (true)
{
    long currentRxBytes = TrafficStats.GetUidRxBytes(spotifyUid);
    long currentTxBytes = TrafficStats.GetUidTxBytes(spotifyUid);
    DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Now;

    // Calculate data usage and speed
    double downloadMB = (currentRxBytes - previousRxBytes) / (1024 * 1024.0);
    double uploadMB = (currentTxBytes) / (1024 * 1024.0);
    double downloadSpeedMBps = downloadMB / 1; // You can adjust the interval (e.g., 1 second)
    double uploadSpeedMBps = uploadMB / 1; // You can adjust the interval (e.g., 1 second)

    // Append data to the CSV file
    File.AppendAllText(csvFilePath, $"{timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")},{downloadMB},{uploadMB},{downloadSpeedMBps},{uploadSpeedMBps}\n");

    // Sleep for the desired interval (e.g., 1 second)
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    // Update previousRxBytes for the next iteration
    previousRxBytes = currentRxBytes;
}
```

I've already tried using other methods but I haven't been able to resolve it. Would anyone have an idea of how to solve this problem?
I need an application to run in an Android environment to monitor a specific application and externalize this data for monitoring.

Comment: the error message tells you exactly what the problem is: `'TrafficStats' is a type, not a namespace.`.  `TrafficStats` is a `type` in the `Android.Net` namespace

Answer (score 0):

> The errors are: CS0138 A 'using namespace' directive can only be
> applied to namespaces; 'TrafficStats' is a type, not a namespace.
> Consider a 'using static' NetUsage directive

Just as Jason mentioned, `TrafficStats` is a type, not a namespace. And `TrafficStats` is a class from `Android.Net` namespace.

So, you can comment out the following code :

```
 //using Android.Net.TrafficStats;
```

and the following namespace is enough:

```
 using Android.Net;
```

Besides, from document [TrafficStats.GetUidRxBytes(Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.net.trafficstats.getuidrxbytes?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13),we know that we should pass a int data as a parameter not two for method `TrafficStats.GetUidRxBytes` :

```
// Get the UID of the Spotify app based on its package name
//int spotifyUid = TrafficStats.GetUidRxBytes(TrafficType.Mobile, PackageManager.GetPackageUid("com.spotify.android"));
```